# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token. Even though I have a constructor?

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to compile my LineADT.cpp file but keep getting this error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
LineT::LineT(PointT::PointT st, MapTypes::CompassT ornt, unsigned int l) {
```

My LineADT.cpp:

```
#include "MapTypes.h"
#include "PointADT.h"
#include "LineADT.h"

LineT::LineT(PointT::PointT st, MapTypes::CompassT ornt, unsigned int l) { //Error 

this->s = st;
this->o = ornt;
this->L = l;

}
```

My LineADT.h:

```
#ifndef LINET_H
#define LINET_H

#include "MapTypes.h"
#include "PointADT.h"


class LineT {

    private:
        PointT s;
        MapTypes::CompassT o;
        unsigned int L;

    public:

        LineT (PointT st, MapTypes::CompassT ornt, unsigned int l);
};

#endif
```

My PointADT.h:

```
#ifndef POINTT_H
#define POINTT_H

class PointT {

    private:
        double xc;
        double yc;

    public:
        PointT (double x, double y);
};

#endif
```

My maptypes.h:

```
#ifndef MAPTYPES_H
#define MAPTYPES_H

class MapTypes {

    public:
        enum CompassT {N, S, E, W};
        enum LandUseT {Recreational, Transport, Agricultural, Residential, Commercial};
        enum RotateT {CW, CCW};
};

#endif
```

What I don't understand is why the compiler doesn't recognize that the line is a constructor (at least what I think).

Comment: clang++ gives a much better error message: "error: constructor for 'LineT' must explicitly initialize the member 's' which does not have a default constructor"

Comment: If I create a default constructor, would I still be able to pass a PointT to the Line Constructor that was created with the proper constructor?

Comment: @Mat: That must be a different error.

Comment: For future reference, this is what an MCVE looks like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8182879caea8eeb1

Comment: Oops looks like I accidentally fixed another bug lol. @TheShield: that would be the wrong fix. Learn about constructor member initializer lists. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.

First:

```
LineT::LineT(PointT::PointT st, MapTypes::CompassT ornt, unsigned int l) {
//                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Nope.

```
LineT::LineT(PointT st, MapTypes::CompassT ornt, unsigned int l) {
```

Second: `PointT` has no default constructor, so you *must* initialise it, not merely assign to it later.

```
LineT::LineT(PointT st, MapTypes::CompassT ornt, unsigned int l)
    : s(st)
    , o(ornt)
    , L(l)
{}
```

As a point of style, I would also recommend using much clearer and more consistent names.